# Show subcategory image in parent product category listing Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set main parent category to show subcategory in top of parent category products page. But now is showing just a [subcategory name](http://www.onexpert.es/cajas-fuertes/), and number of products, but not category image what i set from here:

[category image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVSQG.png)

I tryed to set different product category image for each one, but its not showing in product category listing.. Found this function on [WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/) page, but dont seems to work.

```
/**
 * Display category image on category archive
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

[subcategory without images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xIZX.png)

**EDIT:** I researched a lot, and found that code for that subcategory is loaded into **archive-product.php** file from WooCommerce dir from theme. Inside is this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $shop_display_type == 'subcategories' || $shop_display_type == 'both' ) : ?>

            <ul class="<?php echo ( $shop_display_type == 'subcategories' ) ? 'shop_categories_with_thumb' : 'shop_categories_list'; ?>">

                <?php woocommerce_output_product_categories( array( 'parent_id' => $parent_id, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) ); ?>
```

How to modify this code to show category thumbnail too at top?